# How to integrate Google Tag Manager with React Native app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, google-tag-manager

Recently, the marketing team asked me to add Google Tag Manager in the current company project, this project is written based on `React Native` and I searched a lot for this. but no success to found good updated documentation.

I found a `react-native-gtm` but it is for 4 years ago. also, I find some descriptions for the Native side like [this](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5), but it's exactly for the Native iOS not for a React Native project.

Also, I found an article with the [`React Native: Firebase GTM Integration Installation`](https://adswerve.com/blog/react-native-firebase-gtm-integration-installation/) title. but what is it? What is the meaning of **Firebase GTM**? what does it mean?

Because as I remember these are separated tools for marketing. Firebase is different from GTM. By the way, [this current article](https://adswerve.com/blog/react-native-firebase-gtm-integration-installation/) is not useful for us because it describes installing on the Native sides. it is not a React Native solution.

So: **How to integrate Google Tag Manager with React Native app?**

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I went about this was to handle the integration for both platforms natively. So I assume you already have firebase set up, if not follow guide here: https://rnfirebase.io/

**FOR iOS:**

1. enter the line below into your podfile
   `pod 'GoogleTagManager'`
2. then run: `pod install`
3. in the project root, create a GTM container folder and store the container json file from GTM dashboard in it
   `<project-ios-root>/container/GTM-XXXXXX.json`

**FOR ANDROID:**

1. in your app level `build.gradle` file, add the following to the dependencies block:

> dependencies {
>     // ...
>     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'
>
> }
> 2. Create GTM Containers folder in the following path `<project-android-root>/app/main/assets/containers` and store the JSON file in it as well,
> `<project-android-root>/app/main/assets/containers/GTM-XXXXX.json`

note you will get a build error if your gradle build tool is less than version 4. In that case in your project level `build.gradle` file, update the gradle build tool in the dependencies block with this:
`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")`.

Also, yes "containers" for android and "container" for iOS for the GTM container folder to store the JSON files.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer. Currently, I'm not focus on RN project, but definitely, I will use your solution to my next RN GTM issue.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/google-analytics-vs-firebase-analytics-vs-google-analytics-97ca645a8aff) article very helpful in explaining the differences between Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics.  In short, you need to use Firebase Analytics in the app, with a package like [`react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage). You can integrate tag manager from the console.